# Can I determine the service pack for all my SQL Servers using SCCM?

Tags: service-pack

I'm trying to figure out a way to find out all the service packs for my sql servers. There's about 30+ databases which we hosted & to login to each of the server and check the service pack will going to take some time. Can I use any tools e.g. sccm to crawl into all the sql servers and provide me with the sql versions & it's service packs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is only indirectly database related. This is a question about the capabilities of SCCM in regards to SQL Server and would probably be better asked on serverfault.com under the tag [sccm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sccm). If this question can be formulated to be [on-topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), then please [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/256988/edit) your question accordingly.

Comment: I disagree - it's a question about checking service packs on an RDBMS which is an important thing for a DBA to know!

Answer (score 2):

Very quick and easy solution would be to setup a [CMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/create-a-central-management-server-and-server-group?view=sql-server-ver15) (Central Management Server)

This enables you to run queries on groups of servers.
So if you make a production group, you can run a query on all of them at the same time

Using

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

Would return you all the versions of the group.

If you're managing a bunch of different servers, a CMS is always a very helpful tool.